# When scrolling, if offsetTop is >= element do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resolution

My page has an image (`#braille`) that is at `position:absolute` when scroll is `0`, when scroll is `> 0` it's on `position:fixed`. When scroll is `> 900` some other elements fade in. What I'm trying to do is to make the #braille image "stop" between 2 elements that appear when scrolling (changing the `position:fixed` back to `position:absolute` with a `top:something` that allows it to be correctly positioned between the 2 elements).

I think it's more clear if you look at the JSFiddle I created (I added a text where the #braille image should stop when scrolling):

**http://jsfiddle.net/multiformeingegno/vde7ym94/7/**

Here's the JS script:

```
$(function () {
    var timeoutId = null;

    // hide by default the arrow, the music sheet, the phrase and the yellow circle
    $('#ombra, #logopiano,#presentazione, #frase').hide();
    $("#braille").css({
        "position": "absolute",
            "top": "-56px",
            "left": 0,
            "margin": 0
    });
    $("#ombra").css({
        "top": "-56px"
    }).show();
    var w = $(window).height();
    var c = $("#homescroll").height();
    $("#homescroll").css({
        "height": w + 44 + "px"
    });

    // define the arrow
    var $freccia = $('#freccia1');

    // define the braille shadow
    var $ombra = $('#ombra');

    // define the music sheet image
    var $logopiano = $('#logopiano');

    // define the phrase and the yellow circle
    var $presentazionefrase = $('#presentazione, #frase');
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        scroll = $(window).scrollTop();


        if (scroll >= 900) {
            // events firing when scrolling down
            $("#intro").hide();
            $freccia.fadeOut('slow');
            $ombra.fadeOut('slow');
            $logopiano.fadeIn('slow');
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
                $presentazionefrase.fadeIn('slow');
            }, 500);


        } else {
            // events firing when scrolling (back) up
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            $("#intro").show();
            if (scroll === 0) {
                $presentazionefrase.hide();
                $freccia.fadeIn('slow');
                $("#braille").css({
                    "position": "absolute"
                });
            } else {
                $("#braille").css({
                    "position": "fixed",
                        "margin": "auto",
                        "right": 0,
                        "top": "-56px"
                });
            };
            $logopiano.fadeOut('slow');
            if ($presentazionefrase.css('display') === "block") {
                $presentazionefrase.fadeOut('slow');
            }
            // make the braille shadow image visible only when at the top of the page
            if (scroll < 10) {
                $ombra.fadeIn('slow');
            } else {
                $ombra.fadeOut('slow');

            }

        }
    });
});
```

I thought I could do something like this, but it doesnt work:

```
if ($("#braille").offset().top >= $("#frase").offset().top) {
    $("#braille").css({
        "position": "absolute",
            "top": $("#frase").offset().top + "px",

    });
};
```

The problem is this should work with all resolutions... that's why I thought I could solve this calculating the offset of the braille image from the `#frase` element.

Comment: @Multoformelngegno , you want `#braille` to stop exactly at `#logopianocontainer` or at `#farse` or above them ?

Comment: Between them. Where I put the "BRAILLE IMAGE SHOULD STOP HERE WHEN SCROLLING DOWN" text. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
if ($("#braille").offset().top + $("#braille").height() >= $("#logopianocontainer").offset().top + 90) {
        $("#braille").css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": $("#logopianocontainer").offset().top -  $("#braille").height() + 90 + "px"
        });
    };
```

**[Here a working jsfidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/ep2yacjm/1/)**

Note that I used `$("#logopianocontainer")` insted of `$("#frase")` that is because `#frase` has `display: none` in the moment that `#braille` reaches the position of `#logopianocontainer` so its .offset().top is miscalculated.

On the other hand note the use of the height of the elements that is because when you compare `$("#braille").offset().top >= $("#logopianocontainer").offset().top` this will make the comparison between the top of the elements and you want know when the bottom of the img reaches the position of `$("#logopianocontainer")` and then set the top of `$("#braille")` at the position of `$("#logopianocontainer").offset().top -  $("#braille").height()` the 90 value is a estimated value to positioned the img in the middle of the others two elements.

**Avoid the Jump**

I found why the img jumps, is because you are switching from absolute to fixed again (scrolling back up) when the scroll is < 900 and there is a range where the `#braille` is fixed when supposed to be absolute and when pass the range it jumps to the position.

See here

```
if (scroll >= 900) {
        // events firing when scrolling down
} 
else {
        // events firing when scrolling (back) up

        if (scroll === 0) {
            ...
        } 
        else {
            $("#braille").css({
                "position": "fixed",
                    "margin": "auto",
                    "right": 0,
                    "top": "-56px"
        });
};
```

So you can set a more specific value (950 looks nice) or make it more dynamic for example when `#braille` positioned to absolute put a variable that keeps track of how far was moved down when the scroll down and then when the scroll up, decrease the variable and when the variable is < 0 you switch `#braille` to `fixed` again, this is just an idea, it may be more complex than this.

Comment: THANKS!!!!! It's working great!! :-) Really last thing: is it possible to avoid the little jump when swithing from absolute to fixed again (scrolling back up)? Is that estimated 90 the cause?

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno  the estimated 90 is not the cause, when you remove it still jumps, the jumps is in fat for the switching, I will try to fix it.

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno I added an explanation of why the img jumps

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work fine setting 910. 950 is over the page height and the events are not fired.

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to get the `$("#frase").offset().top`, the value could be incorrect because the `$("#frase")` element has the CSS `display:none` at some moment, due to the use of `show`, `hide`, `fadeIn` and `fadeout`.

The [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) function could not return the offset of a hidden element correctly. You may consider to use `visibility` or `opacity`to do the show/hide trick.

> Note: jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden
>   elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the
>   body element.
>
> While it is possible to get the coordinates of elements with
>   visibility:hidden set, display:none is excluded from the rendering
>   tree and thus has a position that is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But shouldn't it work when the event that makes #frase fade in is triggered?